# How to get Use Case Diagram from Application?

Tags: uml, reverse-engineering, use-case

I am in the process of migrating applications from desktop to web. To migrate I need to reverse engineer to get functional requirements using the case. The application to be migrated does not have documentation. Can I make use cases based on menus on the application? example of the use case of the farmacy menu or the use case menu laboratory

Answer (score 0):

Not really. Or at least you should not try it that way. Use cases are about the added value a system delivers to its actors. You can guess it partially from the menus. But only partially. The only thing you can get from the GUI is some kind of wire framing for classes representing the V in MVC. That's already way beyond use cases.

Comment: So, if I want to make a use case, I have to see which menu of applications the actor uses or needs. Like that?

Comment: Yes, as a start. You need to check the context as well. So WHY is he doing this and that.

Comment: what kind of information does the actor from the system need and what does the system give to the actor, like that?

Comment: Exactly like that. I recommend Bittner/Spence about use cases as excellent read.